# Using a ContentPresenter inside of a MenuItem HeaderTemplate causes a StackOverflowException

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, datatemplate, treeviewitem, contentpresenter

Please observe the following markup:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" x:Key="...">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When this style is added to the application markup file, a `StackOverflowException` occurs at runtime.

The style is being applied to the menu items of a `ContextMenu` which is attached to a `TreeViewItem` (or a subsequent `DataTemplate` for generated tree content); The exception throws when the right mouse button is released and the context menu is due to open.

One of the use cases for the `ContextMenu` is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TviChaptersHeaderTemplate">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,2,0,2">
    <Image Margin="2,0,0,0" Width="16" Height="16" Source="\Icons\pages.png" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0" />

    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Add Chapter" 
                              Style="{StaticResource STYLE}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The exception has been isolated to the `<ContentPresenter />` tag inside the header template. Commenting it out clears the exception. What's going on here?

Comment: I can reproduce the stack overflow you're getting.  However, it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve.  Could you please explain why you're trying to use a `ContentPresenter` in this way?

Comment: Luke- The HeaderTemplate shown in this example is dumbed down in order to highlight the problem. However, the ContentPresenter is actually nested within more complex content in the production code.

Comment: You haven't answered my question.  *Why* do you need to use a `ContentPresenter` this way?

Comment: I'm not really sure why you're asking this. If I'm using the `ContentPresenter` inappropriately (and that's a given, with the exception being thrown), then obviously I'm misunderstanding something. What I'm *trying* to do is wrap the inline content of my MenuItem headers in the visual tree specified in the template.

Comment: So that we're clear, I want to transform `<MenuItem><MenuItem.Header><Content /></MenuItem.Header></MenuItem>` in to the template shown in the post, where the `<ContentPresenter>` acts as a placeholder for `<Content />`.

Comment: I believe `ContentPresenter` holds the entire MenuItem, so you're basically setting up nested `<MenuItem><Header><MenuItem><Header>...` etc. Try using something like `<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />` (That might not be the exact syntax, but you basically want to bind to the `Content` part of the `ContentPresenter`, not the entire thing)

Comment: @Rachel, given the timestamp on your post, we concluded the same thing at the around the same time. You're exactly right. The MenuItem was getting caught by the ContentPresenter and throwing it in to an inescapable loop. `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" />` cleared the issue. If you wish to put up an answer, I'll make sure you get credit.

Comment: @user1124081 Thanks, posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `ContentPresenter` holds the entire `MenuItem`, so you're basically setting up nested

```
<MenuItem>
    <Header>
        <MenuItem>
            <Header>
                ... etc.
```

Try using something like `<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />` (That might not be the exact syntax, but you basically want to bind to the `Content` part of the `ContentPresenter`, not the entire thing)